# Saw a large bike trailer with seating for an adult. Who's making it?

Tags: trailer, disability

A while back in a city (Munich/Germany), I saw a person with trailer attached to the bike:

- The trailer sat a single adult in a long, reclined seat
- No hood/ roof visible
- construction was from tubing and webbing, I think
- Two large bike wheels, probably 28", attached near where the butt of the seated person is
- the seat was between the wheels (relatively low)
- I think the trailer is intended mostly for transporting adults with disablities.

I'm aware of bike trailers for older kids or adults with disabilities that look radically different (Kindercar). The closest thing I know is a  recumbent trike by Haasebikes used as a trailer - however key details from my memory dont fit (wheels wrong size, seat more reclined and with a different backrest, the seating position on the trailer I saw was more to the back than with the Haase trikes). Still, it is possible that I misremember these details. It is also possible the trailer was custom made (There's not a lot of regulation involved with making a street legal bike trailer in Germany.)

From the description above: **Does anyone recognize the trailer and can point me to the manufacturer?**

Comment: Probably not likely to be seen in Germany, but [Wike](https://wicycle.com/products/bike-trailers/large-special-needs-bike-trailer) in Canada makes large, special needs bike trailers. From the description it doesn't match what you're looking for but just thought I would point them out as an option.

Comment: Are community wiki style answers allowed on this site? Could we have a "bike trailers for adults and large kids with special needs" answer? Wike, Haase, Bencycle, Kindercar... Could it be that there are not *many* more manufacturers? This would be such a helpful resource.

Comment: @Kibbee Thanks for the tip re. Wike. I thought they are available here, but afaict there's no reseller for Germany.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am trying to find a trailer for a disabled adult](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/87553/i-am-trying-to-find-a-trailer-for-a-disabled-adult)

Comment: @SamWhited no. However I added my answer to that question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok this is weird. Immediately after posting the question, I googled for used bike trailers for people with disabilities and found the company, Czech republic based [Benecycle](https://reha-buggy.eu/modelle), it's one of theirs:
[image]
(From the company homepage, probably not the exact type I saw)

I swear I'm not advertising, I don't even know if the trailer is any good. I mostly bother with answering my own question because this information is hard enough to find as it is.

Comment: This could be an answer to this question: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/87553/i-am-trying-to-find-a-trailer-for-a-disabled-adult